# System.RAP reported Warning for property IStatelessServiceInstance.OpenDuration error with azure service fabric project

Tags: c#, activemq-classic, azure-service-fabric, apache-nms

I am working on an Azure Service Fabric project which reads a message from ActiveMQ using Apache.NMS .NET library and creating durable consumer to read message from specific from ActiveMQ.

I am able to read the message and everything is working fine, but I am getting some warning as following.

```
'System.RAP' reported Warning for property 'IStatelessServiceInstance.OpenDuration'. The api IStatelessServiceInstance.Open on node _Node_0 is stuck.
```

This warning results in erroring the service, so I need to remove that warning.

Anybody why it's giving me the warning.

Here is a snapshot of how I am reading the message.

```
try
{
    ITopic dest = AMQSession.GetTopic(TopicName);

    using (IMessageConsumer consumer = AMQSession.CreateDurableConsumer(dest, SubscriptionName, MessageSelector, false))
    {
        IMessage message;
        while ((message = consumer.Receive()) != null)
        {
            ITextMessage txtMsg = message as ITextMessage;            
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Close();
}
finally
{
    Close();
}
```

Comment: You [already posted this *same* question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278762/system-rap-reported-warning-for-property-istatelessserviceinstance-openduration) and it was closed due to lack of clarity. There is no added detail in this question. Can you add any details about your use-case, the service you're using/creating, when you see the error, etc.? Just posting the error message isn't really sufficient explanation. It needs more context.

Comment: @JustinBertram can you please look into this now

Comment: It's still not clear at what point you're receiving this warning message. Also, why do you believe this is related to consuming the JMS message?

Comment: What I think is it's related to TCP which listening to get Active MQ message.

Comment: Can you clarify *why* you think it's related to the ActiveMQ client? Also, you *still* haven't clarified at what point you're receiving this warning message. Is it when you start the consumer? Is it when the consumer has received a message and is waiting for another? Is it when the consumer closes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is almost certainly caused by the fact that your code here can block forever. Specifically, `consumer.Receive()` will block forever if no message arrives. As [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/nms/msdoc/1.6.0/vs2005/Output/html/M_Apache_NMS_IMessageConsumer_Receive.htm) states:

> Waits until a message is available and returns it

Also, even if a message *does* arrive the `while` loop ensures that the containing method will never return.

I recommend you specify a timeout when attempting to consume messages. If the timeout elapses then `Receive` will return `null` and the loop will be broken and the code will no longer be blocked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you please share some sample code, how to use timeout with Receive method, that is really helpful.

Comment: FYI, it's resolved using MessageListener